# Asking for a cinema ticket

Tags: translation, colloquial

I'd like to know how to ask (colloquially) for a cinema ticket in German.

In English I'd say

"Can I have a ticket for Guardians of the Galaxy 2 please"

or

"One ticket for Guardians of the Galaxy 2 please".

I just went to the cinema and said

"Ein Ticket für Guardians of the Galaxy 2 bitte"

and the girl understood.

Comment: To not exactly fit one of our close reasons you should state what you think the translation should be and why you are unsure about it.

Comment: I think that would influence the answer negatively seen as though I'm looking for something colloquial.

Comment: Tell us, what you think could be correct. Then we will tell you if you are right or wrong. But we do not translate!

Comment: Okay, I concede. I've added what I said, and I'll ask a friend what they would say to get the uninfluenced answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposal is absolutely fine and very common:

> Ein Ticket für Guardians of the Galaxy 2 bitte.

This is what I would say because it emphasizes even more that you want a single ticket:

> Guardians of the Galaxy 2 für eine Person bitte.

These are also fine:

> Ich hätte gern ein Ticket für Guardians of the Galaxy 2.
>
> Einmal Guardians of the Galaxy 2 bitte.

Instead of *Ticket* you will also often hear the word *Karte*.

Comment: @JosephDieudonné: In German, *Ticket* is a loanword, imported from English. It is well understood, and used more and more, but it's not a German word. The German word is *Eintrittskarte* (literal: *entrance ticket*), but the vast majority just says *Karte* (*ticket* but also *card*). When you drive with the bus or by train, you need a *Fahrkarte* (*riding ticket*) or a *Fahrschein* (literal: *riding certificate*). You can say *Karte* too for this, but its not so common in this case. And do not mix up *Fahrschein* with *Führerschein*. The later is *driving licence*, you need it to steer a car.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: "It is well understood, and used more and more" - in its meaning as an admission permit. In English, the term has a wider meaning (e.g. a "parking ticket" issued for unlawful parking), which is probably not understood well by many German-speaking people.